# Data Transfer Between Databases Automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to transfer data between databases automatically. For example in every one hour, data in one table in first db will be copied into a table in second db.

What do you recommend for me to do ?
By using jobs maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me replication is preferable.

Comment: ETL and a job scheduler will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look at [SQL Server Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx) if you are already on SQL Server 2008. Avoids the need for an additional ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

Create a store procedure and schedule it for one hours:-

```
Create procedure copydata
AS
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.TempTable
SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms169917%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)?
You can set up a package doing what you want it to do and then add it to a job with  a scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "poor man's method".

This logic will you eliminate the need to truncate the destination table every time.

You can schedule a job to call the stored procedure every hour.

OrganizationDB, that is my db name.  Yours may be different.

If your source data is on a different database, use that db's name ....

```
USE [OrganizationDB]
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSource]
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDestination]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSource](
    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeSource] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeUUID] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeSource_SSN_Unique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SSN] ASC
)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSource] ADD  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [EmployeeUUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeSource] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [HireDate]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDestination](
    [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeDestination] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeUUID] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeDestination_SSN_Unique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SSN] ASC
)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDestination] ADD  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [EmployeeUUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDestination] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [HireDate]
GO




IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspPoorMansDataCopy]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPoorMansDataCopy]
Go

/* 

exec [dbo].[uspPoorMansDataCopy] 

*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPoorMansDataCopy] 

AS 



SET NOCOUNT ON 


/* USE SURROGATE KEY */
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDestination
(
    [EmployeeUUID] 
    , [SSN]
    , [LastName]
    , [FirstName] 
    , [HireDate]
)
Select 
    [EmployeeUUID] 
    , [SSN]
    , [LastName]
    , [FirstName] 
    , [HireDate]
From
    OrganizationDB.dbo.EmployeeSource es
where 
    not exists (select null from dbo.EmployeeDestination innerDestination where innerDestination.EmployeeUUID = es.EmployeeUUID)


/* OR USE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT */
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDestination
(
    [EmployeeUUID] 
    , [SSN]
    , [LastName]
    , [FirstName] 
    , [HireDate]
)
Select 
    [EmployeeUUID] 
    , [SSN]
    , [LastName]
    , [FirstName] 
    , [HireDate]
From
    OrganizationDB.dbo.EmployeeSource es
where 
    not exists (select null from dbo.EmployeeDestination innerDestination where UPPER(innerDestination.SSN) = upper(es.SSN))




SET NOCOUNT OFF


GO


GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[uspPoorMansDataCopy] TO public
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is only data from one table and if both databases are on the same server you can also consider creating INSERT trigger on that table that will automatically catch all new data and copy it into secondary database.

I wouldn’t do this though if databases are not on the same server and if servers are not in the same physical location because it might cause performance issues.